# How the stack pointer works on x86 systems

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, callstack

In my Assembly code I initialize the stack like this
In the *.text* section I load a pointer to the stack

```
mov esp, stack_space
```

In the *.bss* section, I allocate 8192 bytes and load the stack like this

```
resb 8192
stack_space:
```

I don't fully understand what memory area my stack occupies.
As far as I know, the stack is growing down relative to the esp.
In other words, if esp points to 0x3000 and its size is 8192 bytes, the stack will be located in the range from 0x1000 to 0x3000. Or not?

Full code *[here](https://github.com/mrjbom/OS/blob/master/source/bootloader.asm)*

Comment: Yes, but stack pointer will almost never point to 0x3000. If you assemble to PE/COFF or ELF executable program, it is the linker and OS loader who decide about stack address and reserved size. In normal circumstances we don't have to explicitly initialize the machine stack. When an ELF32 program starts, ESP=0xffffd600, for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, x86 uses relative and contiguous addressing. [The Wikipedia article on x86 Addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#Addressing_modes) goes into more detail on the displacement equations.